# Autofill password keyboard key lock icon on quickType bar is not showing up - iOS? - have set textContentType = .password?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, autofill

I have set passwordField text content type to .password, but my keyboard does not show up with the key lock icon. :(

I am using iOS 11.2.

```
untf.textContentType = .username
pwtf.textContentType = .password
```

What can be possible reasons, please?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found myself a reason:

At least one password should be added into for key lock icon to appear.

*Settings -> Accounts & Passwords -> App & Website Passwords -> Add Password*

Comment: @Salmaan: Try importing setting bundle. I have not given a shot on this. But try.